# How to draw an axis with fractional units?

Tags: tikz-pgf

With this picture,

[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone} 
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}
                \draw[->] (-5,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$x$};
                \foreach \x/\y in {-5,-4,...,10}
                \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,1.2pt) -- (0pt,-1.2pt) node[below,fill=white]
                { $\y$};
                \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

I do not know how to draw this picture.

[image]

How can I draw it? Is there a general method to present a fraction, e.g 3/20,4/9?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with "general method". You need to write fraction as you like to appear on axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=4]
        \newcommand*{\ar}{1/6}
        \draw[very thick,black,-latex]   (-1.2,0) -- (1.6,0) node[right] {$x$};     
        \foreach \x in {-7,-6,...,9}
        \draw (\ar*\x,1pt) -- (\ar*\x,-1pt);
        \foreach \x/\y in {-5*\ar/{-$\frac56$},-2*\ar/{-$\frac13$},0/{0},1/{1},7*\ar/{$\frac76$}}
        \node at (\x,-3pt) () {\y}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- As I said in comment, it is not clear what you mean with "general method ... you need to write all desired fraction explicite or construct complex algorithm for calculation of fractions.
- If in your scale ticks labels are sparse, the simplest way is write them at selectec ticks, similar as is done in the @Raffaele Santoro answer (+1). For example, desired result as shown in the second image in question, you can get with following (minimalistic) way:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
%\newcommand*{\ar}{1/6}
\draw[thick,->]   (-6,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$x$};
\foreach \x in {-5,...,9}
    \draw (\x,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt);
\foreach \x/\y in {-5/-\frac{5}{6},-2/-\frac{1}{3},0/0,1/1,2/\frac{7}{6}}
    \node at (\x,-12pt) {$\y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]